# jquery two different values to sum up but how?

Tags: jquery, json, sum

I'm having trouble to sum two different kinds of values. I have one value that I get from a json request like so:

```
function bakVormShipping(targetClass){
  $.getJSON('http://shop.com/cart/?format=json', function(data){
    $.each(data.cart.shipping.methods, function(index, methods){
      if (index == "core|10292|40695" || index == "core|10292|40693" || index == "core|10292|40718"){
        $('<strong/>').html('€' + (+methods.price.price_incl).toFixed(2)).appendTo(targetClass); // this is value 1
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The other value is in a div somewhere in a html page, like so:

```
<div class="total">Totaal (incl.btw):
  <span class="grandTotal">
    {{ page.cart.total.price | money }} // this is value 2
  </span>
</div>
```

Is it even possible to sum these two values? If so can somebody please give me some examples or maybe some directions? I've tried numerous things with parseFloat etc. but it returns nothing, NaN or undefined. So some help is more then welcome :)

Comment: I would generally avoid using client-side code to do any price calculations.  That opens the door to someone manipulating that code.  If your server fails to recalculate the price, that let's a good hacker "name their own price".  If the server does recalculate the price, you're doing the same work in two places.

Comment: +1 Eric J. Please for the love of web-standards don't do this in javascript.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Never trust a client app :-)

Comment: @EricJ: Ok never thought of this! Do you perhaps have a better way to do this then? {{ page.cart.total.price | money }} is recalculated by the server. The only thing is that ('€' + (+methods.price.price_incl) isn't added to {{ page.cart.total.price | money }} by default. So do you know a way to do this?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Ok I won't do this ;) Do you know a different and better way to do this?

Comment: @Jaap Vermoolen See the answer to your question. That's what you should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't do a price calculation on the client side ("never trust a client", because they can be hacked.  For that reason, you end up duplicating code on the client and server side).

Instead, look into using Ajax to call back to the server for recalculations, and updates to the web page, as necessary.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

If the server isn't currently performing all calculations you need, the only safe way to fix the problem is to modify the server code.